# Access TensorFloat data

Tags: windows-machine-learning

I am using Windows-Machine-Learning to convert my `VideoFrame` to a `TensorFloat` `_input` (shape: 1,3,256,192; RGB channels + image), load that into my onnx model and receive as `_output` another `TensorFloat` object (shape: 1,17,64,48; 17 detected objects + image).

Now my question: If I want to access that `TensorFloat` `_output`, currently the only way I know is to use `_output.data.GetAsVectorView`, which gives me a long 1d Vector and try to reorder that and figure out how the dimensions are ordered in there? Is there a clear rule that I can follow to understand how the 4D tensor is encoded in the 1D Vector? Alternatively, can I somehow access the different dimensions directly from the `_output` `TensorFloat` object, since using "Shape" shows me that it is a multidimensional array?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the layout of Windows ML tensors here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ai.machinelearning.tensorfloat?view=winrt-20348

A tensor is a multi-dimensional array of values. A float tensor is a tensor of 32-bit floating point values.

The layout of tensors is row-major, with tightly packed contiguous data representing each dimension. The total size of a tensor is the product of the size of each dimension.

Consider:

```
Shape: [D1][D2][D3]...[DN]
Strides: [S1][S2][S3]...[SN]
Location: [A1][A2][A3]...[AN],
```

and you wish to compute the index at Location.

Then, you can assume that:

```
Sn = Dn+1 * Dn+2 * ... * Dn, (for n = 1...N-1)
SN = 1
```

So:

```
index = A1*S1 + A2*S2 + A3*S3 + ... + AN*SN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment.
A specific example would be very helpful: Eg. if our output is shape (1,64,48,3) and NHWC format?
Then how would it be encoded? 
eg.
index = H1 W1 C1, H2 W1 C1, H3 W1 C1, .... H64 W1 C1, H1 W2 C1, H2 W2 C1, .... H64 W2 C1, .... , H64 W48 C1, H1 W1 C2, H2 W1 C2, .... H64 W48 C3